# Wordpress header button gets cut

Tags: css, wordpress, button, header, divi

So I have this header in wordpress where I need to put a button, when landing on the site it looks good, [1st image works good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVVTr.png), but when you scroll, I get a kind of bizarre white box over half of the bottom of the button, [2nd image doesn't work good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1zlD.png). Also, with the searchbox on the side, it's like it doesn't align.

I applied the class "menu-button" to the button, and the following styles:

```
.menu-button a{     
    background-color: #FAA723;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    max-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif!important;
  font-weight: 600!important;
  text-transform: uppercase!important;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
}
```

without these styles, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnmQf.png), it has some kind of padding added under it,

does anyone have the same problem? or is there any method to make a button faster with wordpress using Divi?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Theme Builder or the standard menu?

Using the Theme Builder, you should be able to add the button to your menu with little to no additional css.

Without seeing the actual page you're working on, this is my best guess. If you're using the standard Divi button, then you have the order backward in your css class (for a class defined in module). The Divi menu already defines the max-height via the Customizer, so you can just use that value. Give this a try:

```
a.menu-button{     
background-color: #FAA723;
padding: 20px 25px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif!important;
font-weight: 600!important;
text-transform: uppercase!important;
color: #FFFFFF!important;}
```